# Python Ring cache library: ignore None value

Tags: python, caching, ring

How should I tell `ring.dict` to ignore None value, in other words don't cache if the result of the function is None.

Comment: Ok, just looking into internals, doesn't seem that this is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer on my question is: there is no way to do it. You would need to create your own decorator and it would not be easy.

The simplest way and correct from code perspective is to throw exception in the function that returns result. So if you have like me a function that sometimes can return `None` that you don't want to cache, change your design and make this function to raise an exception in this case.

Comment: I think raising an error is a good idea for the case. it doesn't cache error.